# new FileOutputStream slow, is there a better way?

Tags: java, io

I'm writing a bunch of relatively small files (about 50k or so each).

The total processing time for writing all of these files is about 400 seconds.

I put in some checks to see what's taking the most time and of that 400 total seconds, 12 seconds is spent writing the data to the files and 380 seconds are spent just doing this code:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(fileObj);
```

I would expect the writing and closing of the file to take most of the time but it looks like just creating the FileOutputStream is taking the most amount of time by far.

Is there a better way to create my files or is the file creation just generally a slow operation?  This is the total time for thousands of files by the way, not just the time for a single file.

Comment: According to the Javadoc: "First, if there is a security manager, its checkWrite method is called with the path represented by the file argument as its argument." Can you use a profiler to see what internal methods are taking up all that time? Or I can try that when I get home...

Comment: What OS/file system are you using? Do you have anti-virus software engaged to the file system/directory you are writing to?

Comment: It's on a linux system, i don't know all the details as I'm not the sysadmin for it.

Comment: i tested on windows and the results are generally the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is pretty much normal behavior, its not java-specific.

When a file is created, the file system needs to add a file entry to its structures, and in the process modify existing structure (e.g. the directory the file is contained in) to take note of the new entry.

On a typical harddisk this requires some head movements, a single seek takes time in the order of milliseconds. On the other hand, once you start writing to the file, the file system will assign new blocks to the file in a linear fashion (as long as possible), so you can write sequential data with about the maximum speed the drive can handle.

The only way to make major improvements in speed is use a faster device (e.g. an SSD drive).

You can pretty much observe this effect everywhere, Windows explorer and similar tools all show the same behavior: large files are copied with speeds close to the devices limits, while tons of small files go painfully slow.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was sort of guessing.  So faster drives would be the answer then.

Comment: @TritonMan The file system can also have some impact, as each file system comes with different methods of distributing the file entries on disk and also possibly different guarantees in file system consistency when the operation is interrupted (e.g. by loss of power). But a faster drive (seek time is the limiting part here) always results in improved performance. SSD's do extremely well in such scenarios (small files) because they can eliminate almost all of the seek time compared to a classical hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

Something to avoid that problem and spend the same time in all files is when you give the path of the file delete the extension and when you finish to copy that file, rename the file with the extension you took before. Here is an example:

```
public static void copiarArchivo(String pathOrigen, String pathDestino)
{       
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    // ultPunto has the index where the last point is in the name of the 
    // file. Before of the last point is the fileName after is the extension 
    int ultPunto = pathDestino.lastIndexOf(".");
    // take the extension of the file
    String extension = pathDestino.substring(ultPunto, pathDestino.length());
    // take the fileName without extension
    String pathSinExtension = pathDestino.substring(0, ultPunto);

    try 
    {
        in = new FileInputStream(pathOrigen);
        // creates the new file without extension cause it is faster as    
        // expleanied below
        out = new FileOutputStream(pathSinExtension);

        byte[] buf = new byte[buffer];
        int len;

        // binary copy of the content file
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) 
        {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // when the finished is copyed or and exception occour the streams must 
    // be closed to save resources
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            if(in != null )
                in.close();
            if(out != null)
                out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // the file was copyed with out extension and it must be added after the 
    // fileName 
    new File(pathSinExtension).renameTo(new File(pathSinExtension + extension));
}
```

Where pathOrigen is the path of the file you want to copy and the pathDestino is the path where it is going to be copyed.

Comment: This is more of a hack than a solution

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Can you prove the following statement: "The code fos = new FileOutputStream(fileObj); is making the structure of the the file fileObj and it is faster or slower depending on the file extension"?